# Itext document to match image size

Tags: java, image, itext

I am trying to add image to pdf using iText with `A4` page properties:

```
com.itextpdf.text.Document document = new com.itextpdf.text.Document(
                com.itextpdf.text.PageSize.A4);
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(m_pathToCreateFileIn + "my_web.pdf"));
        System.out.println("New pdf -> " + m_pathToCreateFileIn + "my_web.pdf");
        document.open();
        Image image = Image.getInstance(pngPath);
        image.scaleToFit(com.itextpdf.text.PageSize.A4.getWidth(), com.itextpdf.text.PageSize.A4.getHeight());
        document.add(image);
```

I set both `document` and `Image` to A4 page size and still the image does not fit my document page size.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: That's normal if the image doesn't have the same aspect ratio as an A4 page. Suppose that you put images of people on that A4 page, surely you don't want a collection of people with a very fat or a very thin head depending on the aspect ratio of their picture? Because that's what will happen if you use `scaleAbsolute()` instead of `scaleToFit()`.

Comment: Will now it is much more clear, thanks.

Comment: Anyway, I think it's much better to define the page size so that it has the same size as the image...

Answer (score 2):

You have to add document.newPage() before your changes will take effect, because you can't change the current page. Try:

```
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(m_pathToCreateFileIn + "my_web.pdf"));
    document.open();
    Image image = Image.getInstance(pngPath);
    image.scaleToFit(PageSize.A4);
    document.setPageSize(PageSize.A4);
    document.newPage();
    document.add(image);
    document.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is super late to the party, but I wanted to extend on the answer from @DonKanallie a bit (which was super helpful btw) to be a bit more flexibly in dealing with images of different sizes/dimensions. As the original poster mentioned, my Image was not fitting properly in an A4 output, hence the size of the image taken into consideration and the custom rectangle below

```
        Document document = new Document();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputPath);            
        Image image = Image.getInstance(inputFile);
        //Get Size of Original Image for conversion
        float origWidth = image.getWidth();
        float origHeight = image.getHeight();
        image.scaleToFit(origWidth,origHeight);
        //Set position of image in top left corner
        image.setAbsolutePosition(0,0);
        //Create Rectangle in support of new page size
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(origWidth,origHeight);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fos);
        writer.open();
        document.open();
        //Set page size before adding new page
        document.setPageSize(rectangle);
        document.newPage();
        document.add(image);
        document.close();
        writer.close();
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I tested it rigorously on various image sizes and it worked perfectly. Thanks :)

Answer (score -2):

Try to adjust parameters by x and y axis using this methods.

```
  String imageUrl1 = "";
  Image image1 = Image.getInstance(new URL(imageUrl1));
  image1.scaleAbsolute(140, 190);
  image1.setAbsolutePosition(450, 580);
  document.add(image1);
```

Comment: The question is to match the image with an A4 page. An A4 page doesn't measure 140 by 190 user units. Also, if the A4 page is created from scratch, the offset will be `(0, 0)`, not `(450, 580)`. This is a very lazy answer, hence the down-vote.